# PowerShell XML schema load

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-namespaces

I'm attempting to use PowerShell to get XML content, and then write it to a text file that can be uploaded to SQL Server. Everything I've tried has failed, and I'm finding XML in PowerShell to be a little frustrating.

This is my basic attempt (with shortened paths shown):

```bsh
$xmlpath = 'C:\...\GetCourses\Data\GetCourses.xml'
$xsdpath = 'C:\...\GetCourses\Schema\GetCourses.xsd'
$txtpath = 'C:\...\GetCourses\Csv\GetCourses.txt'
[xml]$xmldata = Get-Content $xmlpath
#This is the only thing that gets me anything
$xmldata.GetElementsByTagName("int")
#This does not work
$xmldata.GetCoursesResult.int | Out-File $txtpath -Encoding ascii
```

Here is what the schema file looks like, that I created from the XML file in Visual Studio:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.kmionline.com/elms" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.kmionline.com/elms" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="GetCoursesResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="GetCoursesResult">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="int" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If I manually format and simplify the XML file to look like XML without all the namespaces, versions, encoding, etc., then it works just fine. But I can't be doing this with every file I generate. I'm not finding anything on the net that works. Please help with any suggestions or advice.

And here is the return response, truncated, formatted for readability.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCoursesResponse xmlns="http://www.kmionline.com/elms">
      <GetCoursesResult>
        <int>109</int>
        <int>1000000375</int>
        .
        .
        .
        <int>1000013568</int>
      </GetCoursesResult>
    </GetCoursesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: did You try select-xml ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-6

Comment: Please show the content of **GetCourses.xml**. Just seeing your *schema definition* won't help us determine why selecting something from your *XML file* doesn't work. Also describe the problem in more detail. What are the expected results? What are the actual results?

Comment: Done. I should have thought to include that. Basically, I want to be able to select the data, without the xml, and save it to an ascii file, whereupon I can iterate over the Course IDs and get additional course information. I also want to bcp the data into a sql server db. All of this I think I can do, but I'm flummoxed with the soap header parts in powershell.

Comment: @Tomek, thanks for the suggestion and the link. The only thing that seems to pull any data is $xml.GetElementsByTagName("GetCoursesResul") or "int". Attempting $xmldata | Select-Xml -XPath "//GetCoursesResult" runs, but does nothing. I really think that the envelope, body, namespaces, etc. are hosing it up somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dot-access has the advantage that you don't have to deal with namespace management. However, you cannot leave out intermediate nodes. To get the values of the `<int>` nodes from your XML sample via dot-access you need this:

```
$xmldata.Envelope.Body.GetCoursesResponse.GetCoursesResult.int
```

If you want to use proper XML selection methods (which provide greater flexibility) you need a namespace manager for handling the namespaces:

```
$nm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xmldata.NameTable
$nm.AddNamespace('ns', 'http://www.kmionline.com/elms')
$xmldata.SelectNodes('//ns:int', $nm)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the suggestions. Unfortunately neither of those suggestions worked. I obviously need professional help. With the first suggestion, it ran but returned nothing. With the second suggestion, it gave me an error, ".. a constructor was not found.."  I really think something in the envelope is hosing it up. For instance, there appears to be two namespaces, and maybe powershell can only handle one. Really not sure.

Comment: And then when I manually delete out
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetCoursesResponse xmlns="http://www.kmionline.com/elms">
</GetCoursesResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Then everything works flawlessly. I can select nodes, write to files, etc.

Comment: @joglidden Both of my code snippets worked perfectly fine when I tested them against your sample data, using the code from your question for populating the `$xmldata` variable. If they don't work for you then your code or your data are not what you said they were. Please update your question with a [mcve] of your code and data, and include the complete, unaltered errors *that code* is throwing.

Comment: I cleared the variables and carefully checked my code, and then re-ran it, and it worked. Thank you very much. I haven't re-tried the namespace manager, but I circle back and do that as soon as I have time.